# Why all the values in second stat are 0

Tags: python-3.x

> **Task**
>   Define two functions f1 and f2 such that,

- f1 returns a list of squares of first 200000 natural numbers using list comprehension.
- f2 returns a generator that computes squares of first 200000 natural numbers.

> Perform profiling of both the functions and which portions of a function consume more time for computing.

- Hint : Make use of runctx method of cProfile module.

> **Solution**

```
import pstats, cProfile

def f1(n1):
    return [i**2 for i in range(1,n1)]

def f2(n2):
    return (x**2 for x in range(1,n2))

cProfile.runctx("f1(n1)", globals(), {'n1':200001}, "Profile1.prof")
cProfile.runctx("f2(n2)", globals(), {'n2':200001}, "Profile2.prof")

s1 = pstats.Stats("Profile1.prof")
s1.strip_dirs().sort_stats("time").print_stats()    

s2 = pstats.Stats("Profile2.prof")
s2.strip_dirs().sort_stats("time").print_stats()
```

> **output is**

```
Thu Jan 23 13:05:23 2020    Profile1.prof

5 function calls in 0.371 seconds                                          

Ordered by: internal time

    ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.363    0.363    0.363    0.363 main.py:4(<listcomp>)   
    1    0.008    0.008    0.371    0.371 <string>:1(<module>)  
    1    0.000    0.000    0.371    0.371 {built-in method exec}  
    1    0.000    0.000    0.363    0.363 main.py:3(f1)      
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objec

Thu Jan 23 13:05:23 2020    Profile2.prof   

5 function calls in 0.000 seconds   

Ordered by: internal time 

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)                     
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method exec}  
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 main.py:6(f2)                                                            
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>) 
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 main.py:7(<genexpr>)    
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Why all value in second are 0(zero)

Answer (score 0):

```
import cProfile

def f1():
    return [i**2 for i in range(1,200001)]

def f2():
    for x in range(1,200001):
        yield i**2

cProfile.runctx("f1()", globals(), locals())
cProfile.runctx("f2()", globals(), locals())
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it